# Keepalives and Server-sent events Signalr

Tags: signalr, server-sent-events, keep-alive

I am trying to see the keepalive events sent from a Signalr server with a Server-Sent event transportation. I am using Fiddler to see it and I have the "Stream" Fiddler feature button enabled...So far I do not see any of them... I am using a Javascript client for that which connects properly with that transport.

Why I don't any HTTP messages on Fiddler sent?

Taking always on consideration that Fiddler is watching HTTP requests/responses where the SignalR server is located...

Thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The end of the following blog post shows how to use Fiddler's COMETPeek feature to inspect ongoing server-sent events responses: http://stevenhollidge.blogspot.com/2013/07/c-client-for-server-side-event.html

[image: COMETPeek]

Comment: Thank you, that has to be one of the less intuitive context menu options I've seen in a while.